# Is it possible to use the sprintf() function in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, printf

I'd like to do something like "Hello %s" and have "World" in another variable.

Of course I could do this simple case using string replacement but if possible I'd like all sprintf() features like argument reordering, which would be very complex to do myself.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a general technique that is powerful enough to solve a large class of problems like yours. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The XML/XSLT equivalent of Hello World is this**:

We have this XML document:

```
<t>Hello <rep/>!</t>
```

**and use this transformation on it**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="rep">
  <xsl:value-of select="'World'"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The wanted result is produced**:

```
<t>Hello World!</t>
```

**Do note**:

1. **We use and override the identity rule**. This is the most fundamental XSLT design pattern.
2. **We can** intersperse a constant content with many different replacement elements and thus **have a "fill-in the blanks" technique**.
3. **Using this technique a full separation between content and processing logic can be achieved**. The XSLT code doesn't know what source XML document it is processing (the document URL can even be passed as parameter). The same XSLT stylesheet can be used any fill-in the blanks document and any fill-in the blanks document can be processed by different XSLT stylesheets. This separation achieves maximum flexibility and maintainability.
4. If you only want **just text to be produced, this can also be done easily** -- for example using `<xsl:output method="text"/>`

Comment: +1 for a good answer that does not invoque extension functions. Also this could be done just with: `concat('Hello ',$s)`

Comment: It took me a while to realize how this solves my problem :) But it does, by "naming" arguments (<rep1/> <rep2/>) I can easily reorder them in the format strings. And thanks for all the notes, too, I do not yet understand them completely but soon I will! :) I'm glad to know both approaches (pure XSLT and extension objects).

Comment: Hmm, it seems like only one answer can be flagged as accepted. But both approaches solve my problem.

Comment: @helix84: Don't worry, Only one answer can be accepted, but many answers can be up-voted and they get +10 reputation points (an accepted answer gets +15). You will be able to up-vote once you yourself have accumulated 50 rep. points (I think). Then you would be able to both accept and up-vote answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are performing the transform inside a language that supports extending XSLT using an extension object (such as one of the .NET languages or PHP); then you can simply create a function to do this and call it from within your XSLT.

Comment: Yes, I'm using XSLT from PHP. Can you please give me an example or link to something similiar like I want to do?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for and the project I'm working on actually uses this approach already.

I'm still thinking of the best approach to pass a variable number of variables to XSLT. These would be the arguments to sprintf(). vsprintf() is also an option if an array would be easier.