# How can these XSLT documents be DRY-ed

Tags: xslt, dry

I have made two pages and now I wonder if I can DRY them.

Here the XSLT:

Frontpage: http://pastebin.com/yuZL913W
dagboek-page: http://pastebin.com/6FGYvpvf (Edited)

Roelof

Sorry one of the links is wrong.
I edited this.

My question is how to DRY these so I can reuse parts. Only the `<div id="posts">` is different. 
I think I understand the fill in the blanks but it is one big xslt file. Is this possible without named templates and call-templates

Comment: For the first stylesheet I'd recommend the "*fill in the blanks*" technique, which will make your code more readable. The second seems OK.

Comment: So , there is no way I can reuse the whole skeleton. The only difference is the content area. Or can that only be done with call-temaplate?

Comment: Here is a short example how to implement "fill-in-the-blanks" : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510420/is-it-possible-to-use-the-sprintf-function-in-xslt

Comment: Oke, I see what you mean. I have to cut the big file into more little pieces. But I don't have a clue how. Can someone give me a example how I can do this

Comment: Roelof Wobben: You can have *one* skeleton XML document that is essentially the HTML in which the dynamically-to-be-generated parts are replaced by xml elements. Your XSLT code will receive the URL/filepath to this document as an external parameter, will use the `document()` function to get it parsed and will apply templates to this document. The static part will be output 1:1 by an identity template. You will write additional templates, each matching one of the xml elements that must be replaced dynamically. Give me a *small* HTML and data-xml-document and I'll provide complete solution.

Comment: That's the wy I worked it out now. But according to you I can do a better job.

Comment: I can make a small page as a a example but I can give you the html and xml file of the page I use now. The html can be found here : http://www.notepadchaos.com and the xml file you can find here : http://pastebin.com/GZPTr2w2. If you can make a small example with it im happy so you don't have to do the whole thing

Comment: Roelof Wobben: OK, I posted an answer demonstrating this technique. Ready to answer any questions you might have. See also the notes at the very end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is one way -- what I call** "*Fill-in-the-blanks*" **to separate content from processing and to parameterize processing**:

**Rendering file (c:/temp/delete/nc3.xml)**:

```
<html  xmlns:gen="gen:gen">
<gen:data from="params" mode="top"/>
<body >
             <div id="outer">
                 <div id="container">
                     <div id="search">
                         <form method="get" id="searchform" action="http://www.notepadchaos.com/">
                             <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" class="txtField" />
                             <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" class="btnSearch" value="Find It " />
                        </form>
                     </div>
                         <div id="title">
                             <h2>Tamara Wobben</h2>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div id="content">
                        <div class="col01">
                                <div class="post">
                                     <h3> <gen:data from="entry/title"/> </h3>
                                    <div class="post-inner">
                             <gen:data from="section/entry/tekst" />
                               </div></div></div>
                              <div class="side-columns">
                             <div class="col02">
                                 <div class="pages">
                                     <!-- hier komen de losse pagina's -->
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="pages-bottom"></div>
                                 <div class="categories-upper"></div>
                                 <div class="categories">
                                    <!-- hier komt het menu  -->
                                </div>
                                 <div class="categories-btm"></div>
                                </div>
                             <div class ="col03">
                                <div class="recent-post" >
                                <!-- hier komen de recente posts -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="postit-bottom"></div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
<br style="clear:both" />
                     </div>
                     <gen:data from="params" mode="down"/>
                </div>
            </body>
</html>
```

**Data file (c:/temp/delete/data.xml)**:

```
<data>
    <params>
    <today>2011-12-29</today>
    <current-time>22:17</current-time>
    <this-year>2011</this-year>
    <this-month>12</this-month>
    <this-day>29</this-day>
    <timezone>+01:00</timezone>
    <website-name>Tamara Wobben</website-name>
    <page-title>frontpage</page-title>
    <root>http://test.tamarawobben.nl</root>
    <workspace>http://test.tamarawobben.nl/workspace</workspace>
    <root-page>frontpage</root-page>
    <current-page>frontpage</current-page>
    <current-page-id>6</current-page-id>
    <current-path>/?debug=xml</current-path>
    <parent-path>/</parent-path>
    <current-url>http://test.tamarawobben.nl/?debug=xml</current-url>
    <upload-limit>2097152</upload-limit>
    <symphony-version>2.2.5</symphony-version>
    <cookie-username>xxxx</cookie-username>
    <cookie-pass>xxxxx</cookie-pass>
    <site-mode>live</site-mode>
</params>
    <events />
          <image>
              <section id="7" handle="images">Images</section>
              <entry id="13">
                 <image size="22 KB" path="/images" type="image/jpeg">
                    <filename>img_5874.jpg</filename>
                    <meta creation="2011-12-19T18:40:04+01:00" width="400" height="267" />
                 </image>
             </entry>
         </image>
         <recent-posts>
              <section id="9" handle="dagboek">Dagboek</section>
                   <entry id="15">
                         <datum time="00:00" weekday="2">2005-02-22</datum>
                         <titel handle="7-weken-echo">7 weken echo</titel>
                   </entry>
         </recent-posts>
<section>
      <section id="6" handle="sections">Sections</section>
          <entry id="12">
               <title handle="even-voorstellen">Even Voorstellen</title>
               <tekst><p>FLOAT : img_5874.jpg</p> 55 56<p>Naam : Tamara Wobben<br /> 57Geboorte gewicht : 2000 gram<br /> 58Geboorte lengte : 44 cm.<br /> 59Geboortedatum : 1 september 2005  </p>
                 </tekst>
            </entry>
    </section>
</data>
```

**XSLT code:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:gen="gen:gen" exclude-result-prefixes="gen">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pFormPath" select=
     "'file:///c:/temp/delete/nc3.xml'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pDataPath" select=
     "'file:///c:/temp/delete/data.xml'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vFormDoc" select="document($pFormPath)"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vDataDoc" select="document($pDataPath)"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$vFormDoc/*"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "gen:data
    [@from='params'
    and
     @mode='top'
    ]">

  <!-- Use $vDataDoc to populate this -->

  T O P   S T U F
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "gen:data[@from='entry/Title']">

  <!-- Use $vDataDoc to populate this -->

  E N T R Y   T I T L E
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match=
 "gen:data[@from='section/entry/tekst']">

  <!-- Use $vDataDoc to populate this -->

   S E C T I O N   E N T R Y   T E X T
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "gen:data
    [@from='params'
    and
     @mode='down'
    ]">

  <!-- Use $vDataDoc to populate this -->

  D O W N   S T U F
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Source XML file (not used):**

```
<t/>
```

**When the above transformation is performed on any XML file (not used), the rendering file is populated with data from the data file**. The templates that process the placeholder `gen:data` elements, are dummy but still demonstrate how this processing works.

**The result of the processing**:

```
<html xmlns:gen="gen:gen">



   T O P   S T U F

   <body>
      <div id="outer">
         <div id="container">
            <div id="search">
               <form method="get" id="searchform" action="http://www.notepadchaos.com/"><input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" class="txtField"><input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" class="btnSearch" value="Find It "></form>
            </div>
            <div id="title">
               <h2>Tamara Wobben</h2>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div id="content">
            <div class="col01">
               <div class="post">
                  <h3>
                     <gen:data from="entry/title"></gen:data>
                  </h3>
                  <div class="post-inner">



                     S E C T I O N   E N T R Y   T E X T

                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="side-columns">
               <div class="col02">
                  <div class="pages">
                     <!-- hier komen de losse pagina's -->
                  </div>
                  <div class="pages-bottom"></div>
                  <div class="categories-upper"></div>
                  <div class="categories">
                     <!-- hier komt het menu  -->
                  </div>
                  <div class="categories-btm"></div>
               </div>
               <div class="col03">
                  <div class="recent-post">
                     <!-- hier komen de recente posts -->
                  </div>
                  <div class="postit-bottom"></div>
               </div>
            </div><br style="clear:both"></div>



         D O W N   S T U F

      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Do note**:

1. This code can populate any rendering document (path passed as an external parameter) using the data from any data document (again path passed as an external parameter). Thus it becomes possible to create different outputs/formats populated with different data.
2. The placeholders (`gen:data` elements) to be replaced with "live content" can have different format and semantics -- no limits to one's imagination.
3. Editors (non-XSLT experts) can work on one or more rendering documents independently from each other and from the XSLT developers.
4. A higher degree of reusability, flexibility and maintainability is achieved.

Comment: Thanks, Which system do you use to make this. I use now Symphony cms because Im on a shared hsoting provider where I don't can use a java solution and because im on a shared hosting I can only a part of a server

Comment: Also ASP.net is not possible because the provider has only ubuntu servers.

Comment: @RoelofWobben: This solution can be used with any hosting system. It only depends on being able to set and pass external parameters to the transformation and to be allowed (some hosting systems may forbid) using the standard XSLT `document()` function. You need to read the documentation of the XSLT processor you are using and learn how to initiate an XSLT transformation from your PL and how to specify and pass parameters to it. BTW, I enjoyed your page. If this answer was useful to you, could you, please, consider accepting it?

Comment: Oke, I found this tutorial of overriding templates for my system : http://symphony-cms.com/learn/articles/view/overriding-templates/ I think the tutorial and your explanation can help me make a better managable site.

Comment: @RoelofWobben: You are welcome. Should you have any XSLT/XPath - related difficulties, please ask questions here and I will be glad to help.

Comment: thanks for the offer and for the patience with me. Have a good new year

Comment: @RoelofWobben: Happy New Year to you, too.