# XSLT vs. XMLDocument Data Type -> cycling through nodes with foreach -> appending to a Literal Control

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, xmldocument

I have a question regarding styling XML in C# using the .NET framework. I'm working on a web site that has 99% of it's data stored as XML. Quite often, I'm stuck to either using an XSLT to transform this XML, or reading the XML into an XMLDocument data type, parsing through it using XPATH, and basically appending the output into Literal server controls throughout the page to handle the display. 
I have a feeling that the latter is much more expensive in terms of memory, as I'm reading the XML into a data type and looping through the nodes with foreach statements and other logical statements. The only reason I typically do this is because I'm much more comfortable doing it this way, and because of I am by no means an XSL guru, it's the only way I can get done what I need to do.
I guess I wanted to know if anyone knows just how much **more** expensive it is doing it that way? And what factors might influence that besides the size of the xml I'm parsing through. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

**It has been shown before, as in [Jon Bentley's classic book](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/) that a bad algorithm implemented in Assembler executes many thousands of times slower than a good algorithm implemented in Basic**.

Therefore, it is simply incorrect to say that "*technology A is faster than technology B*".

As for the memory consumed, it is largely dependent on the size of the XML document(s). Both XmlDocument and a typical XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 processor build a representation of a complete XML document in memory, therefore working with multi-gigabyte XML documents is problematic in both cases.

**[XSLT 3.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-21/) (still in a Working Draft status) has a [streaming feature](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-21/#streaming)** that allows to process an XML document in streaming mode provided the XPath expressions used in the transformation adhere to certain restrictions.

**I believe that it is useful to consider a set of metrics vs only a single one**.

**XSLT is a language designed especially for processing tree stuctures** and as such it offers valuable features that aren't present in other languages. Two examples are *templates* and *pattern matching*.

**Using templates and pattern matching it is possible to express a transformation declaratively**. The code is much more simpler, shorter, easier to understand and maintain, extensible. Writing XSLT code typically can be done in minutes compared to many hours of coding procedural, spagheti - like code in a procedural language.

**Debugging a program in a functional language and even proof of correctness is much easier** due to the fact that variables are immutable.

**Due to the same reason there are much greater possibilities of very aggressive optimization by the XSLT processor**.

Finally, let me rebute a statement made in the otherwise good answer of @dash:

> The xslt can effectively be the output HTML.
>
> On the other hand, with 2 especially, you are then losing out on many
>   of the great features that asp.net can offer, from web forms through
>   MVC. Given that you eventually want to populate an asp.net server
>   control, the way you are doing it is fine, as otherwise you are
>   running xslt just to get values out

**Actually, there is a style of writing XSLT, where there is a strict and clean separation between content and processing** (I call this the *fill-in the blanks* pattern).

See for example, my answer **[to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8674694/36305)**.

**Here are some advantages of developing an XSLT application with this approach**:

1. This code can populate any rendering document (path passed as an external parameter) using the data from any data document (again path passed as an external parameter). Thus it becomes possible to create different outputs/formats populated with different data.
2. The placeholders (`gen:data` elements) to be replaced with "live content" can have different format and semantics -- no limits to one's imagination.
3. Editors (non-XSLT experts) can work on one or more rendering documents independently from each other and from the XSLT developers.
4. A higher degree of reusability, flexibility and maintainability is achieved.

**To summarize**: The approach of transforming XML with a DOM-based procedural language, while possible, is more costly in terms of development resources and results in lesser quality in terms of code complexity, understandability, maintainability and extensibility.

Comment: +1 Totally agree - just wish we had native xslt 2.0 or later support in .Net. Given that, and the OP's current way of doing things was the influence for my answer :-)

Comment: @dash: It is bad to know we are ahead of our time. Knowledge, more often than not doesn't bring happiness...

Answer (score 3):

Xslt works on the same principal; it loads it into a DOM (although typically not XmlDocument - there is a lighter-weight read-only model available - XPathDocument), and executes xpath  expressions (ultimately, looping over nodes).

Badly written xslt can be slow, and badly written c# can be slow. To know which is faster you'll need to profile, noting that it may also be possible to simply improve your current code (no matter which).

Comment: Agreed, but note that a functional program provides opportunities for much more aggressive optimization, due to the immutability of variables / stateless programming.

Comment: Also, XSLT programming can be more elegant, typically requires less development resources, and can result in higher quality in terms of code complexity, understandability, maintainability and extensibility

Comment: @Dimitre it very much depends; I've done plenty of xslt - and I've seen good, bad, and ugly

Comment: @MarcGravell: Agreed. Any tool can be inappropriately used. A chisel can be used to create great sculptures, but it can also be used to kill. My argument is that when two different tools are both appropriately used, we can see that one of them is superior (according to a set of metrics) to the other -- when used to perform a particular job. The reason may be that the better tool was created particularly for that kind of job, while the other  was intended to do other jobs too.

Comment: @Dimitre I think we're on the same page; but without knowing the specific job, it is hard to choose a tool. And many times, either tool will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Marc's answer, there are a couple of other things to think about;

1. Your xslt files can be edited independently of recompiling the code. I worked on a similar system to what you are describing, and the ability to deploy the transformations independently of changing the code was useful; having to recompile and redeploy all of the binaries was a more difficult task than deploying a single xslt.
2. Xslt to HTML can be a lot cleaner than a combination of XML parsing, literals and lots of code behind to set the literals etc. The xslt can effectively be the output HTML.

On the other hand, with 2 especially, you are then losing out on many of the great features that asp.net can offer, from web forms through MVC. Given that you eventually want to populate an asp.net server control, the way you are doing it is fine, as otherwise you are running xslt just to get values out - which isn't really what xslt is for (which is transforming XML from one structure to another).

In terms of performance, you are right, the size of the XML is important. If you have 200 users and they each load a 10mb XML document, and they do it around the same time, then you can see what the overhead is just in terms of data. If it's the same XML document, though, load it once. In fact, cache the results of the transformation or processing, if possible.

Xslt processing is mostly lightweight. Situations where this isn't true is when the xslt uses external functions or is heavily recursive, producing large output documents.

However, sometimes, DOM style processing is much easier than xslt as you can pass around variables more simply, can do more processing using .Net BCL functions etc etc. in this instance, it's worth using XMLDocument and C# code just because it's simpler.

So it really does depend.

Remember, it's always worth trying something then profiling it if you suspect it isn't efficient. This will help you work out what the costs really were. Sometimes this is the only way to decide if something is the "best" way.

Comment: Good answer, but in my answer I disagree about your conclusion following from point 2.

Comment: Oh no, I totally agree - hence the upvote, but it sounds like, at the moment, the original poster already has a lot of code in XML and is just pulling out values using XmlDocument and XPath and pushing those values into server controls (like literal.text for example). It's a very different style to declaratively matching portions and outputting using xslt (in fact one of my favourite apps used xslt to trim down the document and then a pipeline of xsl transforms to output the content. You could argue that Microsoft have made this difficult to do in .Net with lack of in built xslt 2.0 or later)