# Razor view from xml using XSLT

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, razor, webforms

I am trying to display, edit with validation an object which is stored in XML in the database.
It's shape can change over time.
I want at runtime to create a form with validation for each object stored in database.

XMl looks like this :

```
<root>
<name>Name</name>
</root>
```

View:
....
`<form name="formRoot">

      <p>Name</p><input name="name" value="Name"/>

</form>`
....

Do you have any code examples that would help me in this matter, or if there are any libraries that do this already?

Edit 1: in c# i use this kind of xslt http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307322

Edit 2: I want to be able to add validation to each input with regex, length and type validation. Preferably using jQuery. And to do asynchronous validation as I type. For example on blur to send field name to server and get a response with `valid:true` if it's valid and `validation message` if it is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the XSLT part I recommend using the "Fill-in the blasnks" technique** -- see a simple example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8674694/36305.

The form skeleton will look like this:

```
<form name="formRoot" xmlns:gen="my:gen">
  <gen:name/>
</form>
```

The XSLT code will contain a template matching `gen:name` that produces:

```
<p>Name</p><input name="name" value="Name"/>
```

The URL to the form-skeleton is passed as an external parameter to the XSLT transformation.

The source XML document (URL or itself) is passed as another external parameter.

**Thus the XSLT transformation can process any source XML document and insert the results of processing into any form-skeleton document**.