# Generic way to use XSLT to generate text from one "template" XML and another "arguments" XML

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, xslt-1.0, text-processing

I have a solution to my question below but I need it to be more generic so I need help.

The question:

We have a "template.xml" which is composed of a mixture of `<verbatim>` elements and `<argument id='foo'/>` elements both of which may or may not be nested in `<part id='part001'>` elements. (So verbatims and arguments can be in the root element or can be in `<part> ... </part>` elements).

Example "template.xml":

```
<template_root>
  <verbatim>Title</verbatim>
  <part id='part001'>
    <verbatim>Nested in part 1.</verbatim>
    <argument id='keywords'>ARGKEY1, ARGKEY2, ARGKEY3</argument>
    <verbatim>End of part 1.</verbatim>
  </part>
  <part id='DoNotUse'>
    <verbatim>This should not be in the output</verbatim>
  </part>
  <verbatim>End of article</verbatim>
</template_root>
```

We have another file, "instance.xml", which is composed of "< argument id='someid' />" elements (referring to < argument />s in template.xml) which again may or may not be nested in the same "< part id='partid' >" elements as above.

Example "instance.xml":

```
<instance_root template='template.xml'>
  <part id='part001'>
    <argument id="keywords" enabled='true'/>
  </part>
</instance_root>
```

We want a XSLT which reads in the following information from "instance.xml" and generates

1. Read in a template file name (e.g. "template.xml") and then
2. For all elements in the "template.xml":

   21. Copy value of all `<verbatim>` in the `<template_root>` of template.xml as is.
   22. Copy value of all `<argument>` in the `<template_root>` of template.xml only if it is also listed in the `<instance_root>` of "instance.xml" with the same `@id` and attribute `@enabled='true'`.
   23. Do the same as (21) and (22) above for all children of every `<part>` found in "template.xml" only and only if a `<part>` with the same `@id` is also found in "instance.xml" ignoring all other `<part>` in "template.xml".

So what we are NOT copying are:
  1. All `<argument>` in "template.xml" that do not have a corresponding `<argument>` in "instance.xml".
  2. All `<part>` in "template.xml" that do not have a corresponding `<part>` in "instance.xml".

Example text output:

```
Title
Nested in part 1.
ARGKEY1, ARGKEY2, ARGKEY3
End of part 1.
End of article
```

I am using xsltproc and would like to know what a generic way (or the best way you can think of) is to do this? And by "generic" I mean I really don't want to hard code complicated XPaths or refer to individual elements (using [1], [2], etc.).

Comment: Your rules are not entirely clear. Please explain **exactly** which elements not to copy. You say copy a `verbatim`, but do not children of `part`that do not meet some condition - but `verbatim` is also a child of part. If is also not clear what significance, if any, the internal hierarchy of `instance.xml` plays here. And why is your output text, if you are supposed to copy elements.

Comment: Please delete these comments and edit your question instead.

Comment: Done. Is it more clear?

Comment: It might make the job easier as well if we rename `<template_root>` and `<instance_root>` simply to `<part>` and allow `<part>` elements to be nested. That would also work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to @uL1's response and a little more tweaking, below is a very good solution which does the job correctly.

The only missing feature (which I really hadn't asked in my original question but I would really love to add) is to be able to process any number of nested `<part>` elements.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="template" select="document(//@template)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="instance" select="/"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()" priority="1.1">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '&#10;')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/"> <!-- Using match="instance_root" would work just as well. -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$template/*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="template_root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="
            verbatim
            | argument[@id = $instance//argument[@enabled = 'true']/@id]
            | part[@id = $instance//part/@id]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="part">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="
            verbatim
            | argument[@id = $instance//part[@id = current()/@id]/argument[@enabled = 'true']/@id]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solution is already generic enough. Have a look in the below lines:

***expanded*** template.xml:

```
<template_root>
    <verbatim>Title</verbatim>
    <argument id="key">ARGKEY0</argument>
    <part id="part001">
        <verbatim>Nested in part 1.</verbatim>
        <argument id="keywords">ARGKEY1, ARGKEY2, ARGKEY3</argument>
        <verbatim>End of part 1.</verbatim>
    </part>
    <part id="part002">
        <verbatim>Nested in part 2.</verbatim>
        <argument id="keywords">ARGKEY4, ARGKEY5, ARGKEY6</argument>
        <verbatim>End of part 2.</verbatim>
    </part>
    <part id="part003">
        <verbatim>Nested in part 3.</verbatim>
        <argument id="keywords">ARGKEY7, ARGKEY8, ARGKEY9</argument>
        <verbatim>End of part 3.</verbatim>
    </part>
    <part id="DoNotUse">
        <verbatim>This should not be in the output</verbatim>
    </part>
    <argument id="word">ARGKEY10</argument>
    <verbatim>End of article</verbatim>
</template_root>
```

***expanded*** instance.xml:

```
<instance_root template='template.xml'>
    <part id='part001'>
        <argument id="keywords" enabled='true'/>
    </part>
    <part id="part002">
        <argument id="keywords" enabled="false"/>
    </part>
    <part id="part003">
        <argument id="keywords" enabled="true"/>
    </part>
    <argument id="key" enabled='false'/>
    <argument id="word" enabled='true'/>
</instance_root>
```

**Stylesheet:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="instance" select="document('instance.xml')/*"/>

    <xsl:template match="template_root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="
                verbatim
                | argument[@id = $instance/argument[@enabled = 'true']/@id]
                | part[@id = $instance/part/@id]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="part">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="
                verbatim
                | argument[@id = $instance/part[@id = current()/@id]/argument[@enabled = 'true']/@id]
                "/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

*[Hint: Can't work with template matches, cause it is impossible to use variables in template matches.]*

**Result as XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<template_root>
  <verbatim>Title</verbatim>
  <part>
    <verbatim>Nested in part 1.</verbatim>
    <argument id="keywords">ARGKEY1, ARGKEY2, ARGKEY3</argument>
    <verbatim>End of part 1.</verbatim>
  </part>
  <part>
    <verbatim>Nested in part 2.</verbatim>
    <verbatim>End of part 2.</verbatim>
  </part>
  <part>
    <verbatim>Nested in part 3.</verbatim>
    <argument id="keywords">ARGKEY7, ARGKEY8, ARGKEY9</argument>
    <verbatim>End of part 3.</verbatim>
  </part>
  <argument id="word">ARGKEY10</argument>
  <verbatim>End of article</verbatim>
</template_root>
```

**Result as Text**

```
Title
Nested in part 1.
ARGKEY1, ARGKEY2, ARGKEY3
End of part 1.
Nested in part 2.
End of part 2.
Nested in part 3.
ARGKEY7, ARGKEY8, ARGKEY9
End of part 3.
ARGKEY10
End of article
```

You have to change some small things, to achieve your exact output! Change/Add following:

```
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="text()" priority="1.1">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '&#10;')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Most important and maybe drawback: This won't work with `//part/part`! [Can't check `ancestor::part` if all matches the correct `@id`]

Comment: Hi uL1. This looks great and clarifies a lot of stuff. Thanks for taking the time to reply. The only problem I have is that "instance.xml" must refer to which template to use not the other way around. "template.xml" must _not_ refer to any instance file. Could you also explain your hints a little more? What do you mean by "Can't work with template matches" and why do you think we need them? Also what do you mean by "Can't check ancestor::part if all matches the correct @ id" ?

Comment: There are other ways to describe the question. I can try a simpler way to explain the question: We have an "instance.xml", it tells us which template to pick. We have to read the "instance.xml" and copy value of the elements that this instance "enables" from the template that it refers to - in the order that they appear. These elements may be nested but the element paths in instance is what corresponds to the same paths in the template.

Answer (score 0):

**Fill in the blanks** is a well-known XSLT design pattern.

See **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8674694/36305)** for a detailed explanation and actual code.